# Is "Intersects" allowed in DataStax Enterprise CQL query?

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax

When I am trying to execute a query

```
SELECT objectid, field_name FROM spatialtable.solr WHERE solr_query='shape_index:"Intersects(-180.0 -90.0 180.0 90.0)"' LIMIT 1001
```

against a DataStax Enterprise Search instance, I get:

```
An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
SELECT objectid, field_name FROM spatialtable.solr WHERE solr_query='shape_index:"Intersects(-180.0 -90.0...
the Cassandra implementation does not support this method
```

At the same time I can perform shape_index:"Intersects(-180.0 -90.0 180.0 90.0)" query from DSE SOLR Admin Web console perfectly fine. Is it possible to run this query from CQL? If yes, what's the correct syntax?

Thanks, Leon

Answer (score 1):

The CQL interface to solr is pretty limited in what you are able to do. It's not possible to run intersects through CQL, in fact there are a lot of things that won't work beyond simple lucine queries from the CQL side. I recommend you run it (and most of your search queries) through the Solr interface.

Comment: If that's so, it pretty much kills my entire design. I am building a Web app that uses JDBC to talk to various back ends including (possibly) DSE Search. The focus of the app are spatial queries, so if I can't invoke "Intersects" I cannot use DSE Search. Would it be possible to add the ability to invoke SOLR functions from CQL to DSE? It certainly looks as if such queries just need to be passed through to SOLR.

Comment: Probably not in the near future. I would suggest that you use the solr interface to do it.